the limit of log-sum-exp under continous condition
$f(x)\in C(\Omega)$ and $\Omega$ is a closed bounded set, now I want to proof $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\varepsilon\log{\left(\int_{\Omega}{e^{\frac{f(y)}{\varepsilon}}dy}\right)}=\max f(y)$. However, I can not find the low bound which is simple under the dicrete condition. Does anyone have some suggestions?
let $f^*=\mathop{\max}\limits_{y\in\Omega}f(y)$, then we have:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \mathcal{M}_{\varepsilon}(f)&=\varepsilon\log{\left(\int_{\Omega}{e^{\frac{f(y)}{\varepsilon}}dy}\right)},\\
        &=f^*+\varepsilon\log{\left(\int_{\Omega}{e^{\frac{f(y)-f^*}{\varepsilon}}dy}\right)},\\
        &\le f^* + \varepsilon\log{|\Omega|}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
